# play framework 2.1 - scheduling async tasks

Tags: playframework-2.0, scheduled-tasks, akka, playframework-2.1

In play's 2.0.x doc you can see how to schedule asynchronous tasks:

http://www.playframework.org/documentation/2.0.4/ScalaAkka

```
Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 30 minutes, testActor, "tick")
```

How can you achieve the same thing withthe recently releades Play 2.1???

The whole akka API seems to have changed...

I've checked:

https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Highlights
https://github.com/playframework/Play20/wiki/Migration
and also
http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.1.0-RC1/project/migration-guide-2.0.x-2.1.x.html

also asked here: https://groups.google.com/d/topic/play-framework/7VcwNea6QlM/discussion

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Using [sample code](https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/2.1-RC1/samples/scala/websocket-chat/app/models/ChatRoom.scala) and [Akka API](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.4/scala/scheduler.html) I made fast test, works for me.

Comparing code between 2.0.4 and 2.1RC1 I can see there're only two changes in case of scheduler:

1. replaced import

   ```
   // import akka.util.duration._
   import scala.concurrent.duration._
   ```
2. added import:

   ```
   import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
   ```

`app/controllers/Application.scala`

```scala
package controllers

import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._
import play.libs.Akka

import akka.actor._
import scala.concurrent.duration._
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._

object Application extends Controller {

  def index = Action {

    // say hello
    Logger.info("hello, index action started")

    val Tick = "tick"
    val Tack = "tack"

    val tickActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props(new Actor {
      def receive = {
        case Tick => Logger.info("that still ticks!")
        case Tack => Logger.warn("... 7 seconds after start, only once")
      }
    }))

    // Repeat every 5 seconds, start 5 seconds after start
    Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(
      5 seconds,
      5 seconds,
      tickActor,
      Tick
    )

    // do only once, 7 seconds after start
    Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(7 seconds, tickActor, Tack)

    Ok(views.html.index("Your new application is ready."))
  }

}
```

**Edit**

Nota bene, as I can see from Julien's post on the group, that's enough to import `defaultContext` only:

```scala
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
```

Answer (score 9):

[biesior's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469308/11236) is great

However, you don't *have* to go through an actor if you don't want to. Here's the same answer using good old `java.lang.Runnable`:

```
Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(5 minutes, 5 minutes, new Runnable {
  def run() {
    Logger.info("that still ticks!")
  }
})
Akka.system.scheduler.scheduleOnce(7 minutes, new Runnable {
  def run() {
    Logger.warn("... 7 seconds after start, only once")
  }
})
```

Answer (score 2):

For example run a task every Saturday at 15 AM in java:

```
DateTime now = new DateTime();

DateTime plannedStart = new DateTime()
    .withDayOfWeek(DateTimeConstants.SATURDAY)
    .withHourOfDay(15)
    .withMinuteOfHour(0)
    .withSecondOfMinute(0)
    .withMillisOfSecond(0);

DateTime nextRun = (now.isAfter(plannedStart))
    ? plannedStart.plusDays(7)
    : plannedStart;

Long nextRunInSeconds = (long) secondsBetween(now, nextRun).getSeconds();

Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
    Duration.create(nextRunInSeconds, TimeUnit.SECONDS),
    Duration.create(7, TimeUnit.DAYS) ,
    new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Logger.info("-------------------------scheduler start : " + new DateTime());
        }
    },
    Akka.system().dispatcher()
);
```