# How to schedule an hourly job with Play Framework 2.1?

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.1

In Play 1 it was simply:

```
@Every(value = "1h")
public class WebsiteStatusReporter extends Job {

    @Override
    public void doJob() throws Exception {
        // do something
    }
}
```

What is the equivalent for Play 2.1?

I know that Play uses akka and I [found this code sample](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaAkka):

```
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits._
Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 30.minutes, testActor, "tick")
```

But being a Scala noob I don't understand how works. Can someone provide a complete, working example (end to end)?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is an extract from a [code of mine](https://github.com/ndeverge/twivent/blob/master/app/Global.scala#L28):

```
import scala.concurrent.duration.DurationInt
import akka.actor.Props.apply
import play.api.Application
import play.api.GlobalSettings
import play.api.Logger
import play.api.Play
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Execution.Implicits.defaultContext
import play.api.libs.concurrent.Akka
import akka.actor.Props
import actor.ReminderActor

object Global extends GlobalSettings {

  override def onStart(app: Application) {

    val controllerPath = controllers.routes.Ping.ping.url
    play.api.Play.mode(app) match {
      case play.api.Mode.Test => // do not schedule anything for Test
      case _ => reminderDaemon(app)
    }

  }

  def reminderDaemon(app: Application) = {
    Logger.info("Scheduling the reminder daemon")
    val reminderActor = Akka.system(app).actorOf(Props(new ReminderActor()))
    Akka.system(app).scheduler.schedule(0 seconds, 5 minutes, reminderActor, "reminderDaemon")
  }

}
```

It simply starts a daemon at the start of the app, and then, every 5 minutes. It uses Play 2.1 and it works as expected.

Note that this code uses the [Global object](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal) which allows to run some code on application startup.

Comment: Interesting. However, still, my onStart() method isn't called using the above code...

Comment: Because you have to use the Global object as mentioned in my answer. The `Global.scala` has to be store in your app folder (without any package)

Comment: Convention over configuration :( It finally works! thanks a lot

Comment: Good answer, lots of example code misses WHERE to put the jobs. Thanks.

Comment: FYI, `Global.java` uses play.Application, `Global.scala` uses play.api.Application. To use `play.Application` in the above, call  `play.Application#getWrappedApplication`

Answer (score 4):

An example:

```
case object Tick

class TestActor extends Actor {

  def receive = {
    case Tick => //...
  }
}

val testActor = Akka.system.actorOf(Props[TestActor], name = "testActor")

Akka.system.scheduler.schedule(0.seconds, 30.minutes, testActor, Tick)
```

Comment: What are `0.seconds` and `30.minutes`? These don't compile for me.

Comment: I'm getting `expected class or object definition` when play compiles the first line of code after the class (regardless of what it is). Any idea why?

Comment: Use this import for the `seconds` part: `import scala.concurrent.duration._`

Comment: The second question is a bit hard to answer. If you can not figure out the problem you could open a new stackoverflow question with the source code and enough details. I reckon it's a typeo though, a character in the wrong place.

Comment: Here is the code - does it warrant a separate question? https://gist.github.com/ripper234/5032788

Comment: Ahh, place all the code (apart from the imports) into an object, like this: `object test { ... }`. At the toplevel of files you can only declare classes and objects.

Comment: Ah, great, that compiles (https://gist.github.com/ripper234/5032857). Problem is ... it still does't run. What do I do in order for it to run properly?

Comment: BTW you can also use `0 seconds` instead of `0.seconds`

Comment: In order to run it you can either create a main method, [extend `App`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.App) or call the init object from a REPL. Objects are lazily instantiated

Comment: I understand the prefered way is to place a Global.scala file in /app folder - http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/ScalaGlobal

Comment: Oh yeah for within a play application definitely. I thought you meant running the example (https://gist.github.com/EECOLOR/5033368)

Answer (score 3):

Take a look into [Akka's doc](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/2.0.5/scala/scheduler.html)

sample you gave is:

```
def schedule(
  initialDelay: Duration,
  frequency: Duration,
  receiver: ActorRef,
  message: Any): Cancellable
```

Means: start 0 seconds from now, at every 30 minutes send to the actor `testActor` message  `Tick`

what's more for simple tasks you probably don;t need to use Actors - you can just schedule the new Runnable:

```
  def schedule(
    initialDelay: Duration, frequency: Duration, runnable: Runnable): Cancellable
```

[More detailed description in other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13469308/1066240)

Comment: Could you look at my correspondence with EECOLOR? This is the last code I reached, and it compiles, but doesn't do anything. https://gist.github.com/ripper234/5032857

Comment: Maybe I missed something, but usually schedulling tasks goes to Global object (as just @nico_ekito showed :P)

Answer (score -1):

A simple play scheduler without using Actors.

It can be done using org.quartz.scheduler and calling the scheduler from the Global class.

[Sample scheduler](https://github.com/hynek-jemelik/scheduler)

Comment: This may theoretically answer the question, but it would be best to include the essential parts of the answer here for future users, and provide the link for reference. [Link-dominated answers](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231) can become invalid through [link rot](//en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Link_rot).

Comment: Thanks. Will avoid it in the future.