# Migration from Play Framework 2.0.x to 2.1, how to shedule tasks?

Tags: scala, migration, playframework-2.0, akka, schedule

My question is similar to this: [play framework 2.1 - scheduling async tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13466047/play-framework-2-1-scheduling-async-tasks).

But I am kinda scala noob, I want to know how to shecule tasks by java code.
My java codes in 2.0.x is:

```
        Akka.system().scheduler().schedule(
                Duration.Zero(),
                Duration.create(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES),
                arf, "TICK_TICK"
                );
```

It works well in play 2.0.x, but in 2.1 the function schedule() need another arg.
I searched in Akk API, it is:

```
          Cancellable schedule(scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration initialDelay,
                 scala.concurrent.duration.FiniteDuration interval,
                 ActorRef receiver,
                 java.lang.Object message,
                 scala.concurrent.ExecutionContext executor)
```

Now, I think need to add an executor, but I dont know how to fill the fifth parameter.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The answer you're looking for is available in [this page](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.0/JavaAkka) of the Play! Framework documentation.